# Create whatsapp type contact list by quick blox android

Tags: android, contacts, quickblox

I am registering new users from my app using his contact number on quick blox panel.
There is a method provided by quick blox which give me all the user registered through my app.
User can be registered on quick blox through multiple device.
When i try to fetch user list from quick blox panel it give me all the users registered on quick blox.
But i want only those users which are in my contacts list.(contact number=user Login).
Currently i am filtering the records by comparing my contacts with the user   returned by quick blox panel.
There is 2500 contacts in my phone and 3000 all the user on quick blox panel.
When i try to filter this by comparing both the contacts it takes long time.
Is there any solution for this.

Comment: Does quickblox user updates frequently ? if not then you can store the id on your local storage, only compare after a day or a week whichever interval you prefer.

Comment: Yes user are updating frequently

Comment: In the end you have to keep the relationship, if you can query users between times then you can only update those users which are updated after certain date.